# Difference between Equi-Join and Inner-Join in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables called '**table123**' and '**table246**'.

'**table123**' columns: '*ID*', '*Dept_ID*', '*First_Name*', '*Surname*', '*Salary*', '*Address*'.

'**table246**' columns: '*Dept_ID*', '*Dept_Name*'.

I want to find the list of employees with the lowest salary per department. Two of the ways I can do it is an **Equi-Join** or an **Inner-Join**. I've been told they can both be used to provide the desired result.

The queries I used:

**Equi-Join:**

```
SELECT First_Name, b.Dept_Name, alt.Min_Salary AS Min_Salary
FROM table123 a, table246 b,
(SELECT Dept_ID, MIN(Salary)Min_Salary
FROM table123
GROUP BY Dept_ID)alt
WHERE a.Dept_ID = b.Dept_ID
AND a.salary = alt.Min_Salary
AND a.Dept_ID = alt.Dept_ID;
```

**Inner-Join:**

```
SELECT MIN(Salary)Min_Salary, Dept_Name
FROM table123 a, table246 b
INNER JOIN (SELECT First_Name, MIN(Salary)
FROM table123
GROUP BY Dept_ID)alt
ON b.Dept_ID = alt.Dept_ID;
```

The Equi-Join statement gives me the desired table, containing the columns 'First_Name', 'Dept_Name' & 'Min_Salary', with all relevant data.

However, the Inner-Join statement doesn't run because the First_Name column needs to be included in the aggregate function or GROUP BY clause. This really confuses me, as I don't know how to go about fixing it. How can I adjust the Inner-Join query, so as to give the same result as the Equi-Join query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.First_Name, b.Dept_Name, alt.Min_Salary AS Min_Salary
FROM table123 a
INNER JOIN table246 b
    ON a.Dept_ID = b.Dept_ID
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT Dept_ID, MIN(Salary) Min_Salary
            FROM table123
            GROUP BY Dept_ID
           ) alt
    ON b.Dept_ID = alt.Dept_ID
WHERE a.Salary = alt.Min_Salary;
```

Comment: My fault, I didn't type it correctly. The query runs, but it brings back all the records from one table. I just want the minimum salary from each Dept_Name, so there should only be 6 rows.

Comment: Try the new query in my answer

Comment: Okay, the second query works fine, but it doesn't include the First_Name of the employee who has that lowest salary. That was the problem I encountered at the start.

Comment: I have updated the first query with a WHERE clause. That should give your desired result

Comment: The latest edit is perfect, now it shows the desired result. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You got most of the basic parts of the query already, which is a good start. Basic rule is when you need to reduce the rows based on a condition, use a WHERE clause. For table joins, always start simple, joining each table one after the other and checking the results. Hope that's helpful

Comment: WHERE a.Salary = alt.Min_Salary, means only return salaries in "a" that are equal to salaries in "alt". The INNER JOIN ensures only records that satisfy this condition is returned.

Comment: Number of joins depends on the kind of result you want. In this case, you had to join table123 & table246 because you wanted columns from both. The 3rd join was necessary to derive the the minimum salary in each Dept_ID, and then join back to the first 2 tables. Regarding the dot notations (table aliases), you can use any one you like. They are only table labels and makes the syntax nicer. For example, table123 had alias "a" and table246 was "alt". These could have been  "T1" and "T2" respectively, then the last statement would change to  WHERE T1.Salary = T2.Min_Salary.

Comment: Yes that is correct. No worries. I am always happy to help.

Comment: I will get back to you later today.

Comment: Try https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/querying-microsoft-sql-server-2012-databases-jump-start-8241?l=WFbhCtJy_7204984382

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139322/discussion-between-mayowao-and-crashbandicoot).